# Elasticsearch multi date range aggregation using java api

Tags: elasticsearch

I use elasticsearch 2.2 and I want to do some aggregations like this:

```
{  
   "bool":{  
      "must":[  
         {  
            "query_string":{  
               "default_field":"berid",
               "query":"F600-HHP1"
            }
         },
         {  
            "query_string":{  
               "default_field":"matnr",
               "query":"91P9289AAZZ"
            }
            }
         ]

   },
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{  
      "count_by_date_range":{  
         "date_range":{  
            "field":"zzupload",
            "ranges":[  
               {  
                  "from":"2016-03-01",
                  "to":"2016-03-06"
               },
               {  
                  "from":"2016-03-07",
                  "to":"2016-03-13"
               },
               {  
                  "from":"2016-03-14",
                  "to":"2016-03-20"
               },
               {  
                  "from":"2016-03-21",
                  "to":"2016-03-27"
               },
               {  
                  "from":"2016-03-28",
                  "to":"2016-04-03"
               },
               {  
                  "from":"2016-04-04",
                  "to":"2016-04-10"
               },
               {  
                  "from":"2016-04-11",
                  "to":"2016-04-17"
               },
               {  
                  "from":"2016-04-18",
                  "to":"2016-04-24"
               },
               {  
                  "from":"2016-04-25",
                  "to":"2016-05-01"
               },
               {  
                  "from":"2016-05-02",
                  "to":"2016-05-08"
               },
               {  
                  "from":"2016-05-09",
                  "to":"2016-05-15"
               },
               {  
                  "from":"2016-05-16",
                  "to":"2016-05-22"
               },
               {  
                  "from":"2016-05-23",
                  "to":"2016-05-29"
               },
               {  
                  "from":"2016-05-30",
                  "to":"2016-06-05"
               },
               {  
                  "from":"2016-06-06",
                  "to":"2016-06-12"
               },
               {  
                  "from":"2016-06-13",
                  "to":"2016-06-19"
               }
            ]
         },
         "aggs":{  
            "total_fcst_qty":{  
               "sum":{  
                  "field":"zzamqtu"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I need to calculate the sum of quantity on date range("from":"2016-03-01",               "to":"2016-03-06", ...).But it's look like elasticsearch java api didn't support multi date_range.Here is my code:

```
        SearchRequestBuilder searchBuilder = esClient.prepareSearch(Elasticsearch_sap_material_fcst_Index)
        .setTypes(Elasticsearch_material_fcst_Type)
        .setQuery(sb.toString())
        .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.dateRange("count_by_date_range").field("zzupload")
                .addRange("2016-03-01", "2016-03-06")
                .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.sum("total_fcst_qty")));
```

How to calculate multiple date range using java api? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just add multiple ranges like you did with the REST API:

```
SearchRequestBuilder searchBuilder = esClient.prepareSearch(Elasticsearch_sap_material_fcst_Index)
        .setTypes(Elasticsearch_material_fcst_Type)
        .setQuery(sb.toString())
        .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.dateRange("count_by_date_range").field("zzupload")
                .addRange("2016-03-01", "2016-03-06")
                .addRange("2016-05-23", "2016-05-29")
        .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.sum("total_fcst_qty")));
```

If you have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/bucket/range/AbstractRangeBuilder.java#L47), you can see that each call to addRange appends the new range to a list of ranges.